# Measuring requests per second

Tags: nginx, devops

Parse.com has a very useful tool in which it graphs the number of requests per second made to your application across a given time. I was wondering for an Nginx configuration, is there any tool that does the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Nginx Plus](https://www.nginx.com/products/live-activity-monitoring/) would be another option to parsing the logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ngx_http_stub_status` module (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html) to export basic information, combined with `collectd`'s nginx plugin (https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:nginx).